# How to delete nested lists with None in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists with `None`'s and I would like to delete the two lists so that data becomes empty. But for some reason it seems the `for` loop is aborted after the first list is deleted, what am'I missing ?

```
data = [[1531785600000, None, None, None, None, 0.0], [1531872000000, None, None, None, None, 0.0]]

for i,d in enumerate(data) :
    if None in d :
        del data[i]
data
Out[128]: [[1531872000000, None, None, None, None, 0.0]]

# Expected result :
data
Out[130]: []
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never delete elements from a list in an enumerate loop. Because once you delete `data[0]` in the first iteration, the list itself id now modified and has only one element, so the next `enumerate` does not return anything (it thinks it has already looped through all elements).

Better way to do this:

```
data = [x for x in data if None not in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[1531785600000, None, None, None, None, 0.0], [1531872000000, None, None, None, None, 0.0]]
```

### Imperative approach

```
y = []

for i in x:
    if None not in i:
        y.append(i)

print(y)
```

### List comprehension

```
y = [i for i in x if None not in i]
print(y)
```

### Output:

> []

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting member of data array while you are iterating the same array. That's never good solution.

For removing members of data that contains None you can try this:

```
data = [[1531785600000, None, None, None, None, 0.0], [1531872000000, None, None, None, None, 0.0]]

data = [d for d in data if None not in d]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data = [[1531785600000, None, None, None, None, 0.0], [1531872000000, None, None, None, None, 0.0]]

del data[:]

Output: []
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunnatly it also delete nested list that haven't `None`.